# Running separate epoll loop in tornado

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, websocket, tornado

Im running a tornado application that has a periodic callback function that sends a message to every connection. e.g.:

```
def broadcast():
    for c in webSocketConnectionList:
        c.write_message("message")
```

the above code is similar to what I have and runs every 500 seconds from a periodic callback attached to the IOLoop. What I'd like to do though is have this run asynchronously to the ioloop. That is, this method continually repeats itself using an infinite loop.

so the question is : **how can I loop this method asynchronously to the IOloop?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you mean, "asynchronously to the IOLoop." Can you explain more about what you're trying to do?

If you want to replace your PeriodicCallback with an infinite loop, do this:

```
from datetime import timedelta

from tornado import gen, ioloop


@gen.coroutine
def broadcast():
    loop = ioloop.IOLoop.current()
    while True:
        print "broadcast"
        for c in webSocketConnectionList:
            c.write_message("message")

        yield gen.Task(loop.add_timeout, timedelta(seconds=500))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    broadcast()
    ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

The `yield` statement allows the loop to keep running and processing other events (like HTTP requests) while the `broadcast` method is paused.